# How to find the datasets for skill test (like java, python, c c++, etc.)

Tags: data-mining, nlp, dataset, data

I want to extract the **skills** from a resume using Natural languge processing.

To train my model I don't any dataset. where can I get a sample dataset for extracting skills from resume?

Comment: can you ask the question a bit clearly, are you looking for a dataset to perform skill extraction?

Comment: @Toros91, Suppose you have a Reume of any person and you have to find the skill from resume. for checking skill you need to data sets for skill or How can you find?

Comment: This question is probably a better fit at https://opendata.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

a) You may try to find an anonymized resume dataset in the openbase of [Kaggle datasets](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets)

b) You may do some web scraping on professional social networks like LinkedIn (take the description of a profile as resume, and the LinkedIn skills as supervised training set) to build your own sample database (do not forget to anonymize it).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think as [Taamer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/42401/taamer) has suggested, you should start exploring the sites like [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets), attached a link too for extracting the training dataset. [Link-1](https://www.kaggle.com/c/facebook-recruiting-iii-keyword-extraction) Web scrapping using professional networks like LinkedIn, Hire etc. This is just an extension for Tammers answer.

Comment: I didn't get any useful data sets from kaggle.